# Webpack chunkFilename hyphenating file path [name] - Can I keep path intact?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, babeljs, laravel-mix

I've got a folder structure

```
/resources/assets/js/campaigns/2018/jan/Example.vue
```

Which is currently generating chunks to to:

```
/public/js/chunks/campaigns/2018-jan-Example.js
```

---

### Is there a way to do this?

However, due to the size of the project I'm working on, it would be nice to keep the folder structure and generate this instead:

```
/public/js/chunks/campaigns/2018/jan/Example.js
```

---

### My Files

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].chunk.js',
        publicPath: '/js/'
    }
})

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

**Master.vue**

```
    methods: {
        loadPage(path) {

            this.page = () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "campaigns/[request]" */ `../campaigns/${path}`)
        },
```